# Hibernate mapping of similar columns

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

if I create a table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user`(
    `id`            INT     NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email_1_type`  INT     NULL,
    `email_1`       VARCHAR(255)    NULL,

    `email_2_type`  INT     NULL,
    `email_2`       VARCHAR(255)    NULL,

    `email_3_type`  INT     NULL,
    `email_3`       VARCHAR(255)    NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

can I map `email` columns as list? Like:

```java
public class Email{
    private int type;
    private String email;

    // getter & setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "info_req_chat_time_detail")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private List<Email> emails;

    // getter & setter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Java collections types are used to map relationships to other tables that need foreign keys.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html

> As a requirement persistent collection-valued fields must be declared
>   as an interface type (see Example 7.2, “Collection mapping using
>   @OneToMany and @JoinColumn”). The actual interface might be
>   java.util.Set, java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Map,
>   java.util.SortedSet, java.util.SortedMap or anything you like
>   ("anything you like" means you will have to write an implementation of
>   org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType).

It actually would be good design to have another table of just `Phones` containing of  `id(FK), emailType, emailValue`. Then you could do what you're listing.

But if you're trying to keep it simple and know for sure about 3 phones, don't do that. You never know when you'll want to modify or augment just one of the SQL columns. If you need to use a List in the Java class, build a `private List<Email> getAllEmailsAsList()` method collecting all the individual email fields and packaging them into a list for you.

There's nothing wrong with having the 6 extra member fields in your `@Entity` class to handle this table's creation.

Comment: I do that since I'm sure I only need up to 3 emails and also I want to decrease the selecting

Comment: You're sure now, but what happens in version 2.0 of the software when the client says, "I want each contact to have an unlimited amount of emails!" ? See my update to my answer though, I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. Set them each individually.